# Php with APC or PHP Hip-hop

Tags: php

i want to know that PHP with Opcode cache is fast or just Facebook Hip-Hop

Thanks

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form. Please add much more detail about the nature of your site, its technical structure, visitor frequency etc.

Comment: i am on single server and using APC and it is working good but i dont know that Hip-Hop is useful or not ?(i am using Joomla on my community site and regular visitor if the site in a day are 10k+)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HipHop instead of XCache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467899/hiphop-instead-of-xcache)

Answer (score 1):

Hip-Hop is compiled PHP modules/C. PHP Opcode cache saves the interpreted PHP so it can be used next time, without the overhead. So they are not exactly the same.

I have yet to use Hip-Hop, but its sheer existence and the fact that it doesn't have the overhead of a caching layer, *could* make it faster.